# CI Site not working after transferring to new server (godaddy shared hosting)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need immediate help. I transferred my CI site from one server to another and it stopped working, now it is showing 404 error. I tried setting basepath to '' and also to server URL but still same issue. What could be the solution of this, please help.

Comment: First place to look is mod_rewrite and your .htaccess file (specifically, url rewriting).

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file. @PuneeshGoyal

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to look at.

First, make sure that `$config['base_url']` is set in application/config/config.php

Second, controller and model files must begin with a capital letter. An example: controllers/Index.php, models/Index_model.php and the file names and class name must match.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your htaccess file on new server.